# How to scan white on Black barcode android,(inverted can)?

Tags: android, zxing, barcode-scanner, zbar

I would like to scan white on black barcode in android.I have used zxing and it allows me to scan only black on white.
How can i scan and inverted barcode or which library to use?
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3):

If you are still looking in reference to the journeyapps embedded zxing scanner,
`integrator.addExtra(Intents.Scan.INVERTED_SCAN, true);`

Comment: how to add this?

Comment: @BMM Hey man, sorry for the late reply.  
Have a look at [this](https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/example/zxing/MainActivity.java)

Answer (score 2):

I banally inverted the `byte[]` coming from the camera preview this way

```
  for (int y = 0; y < data.length; y++) {
       data[y] = (byte) ~data[y];
  }
```

before passing it down to `ZXing`. I had two support both ways, so I banally decided to invert every `n` times. It might be not efficient or too smart, but in my case was simple and good enough

Comment: Where do you invert that.Because i does not even read the barcode.Thanks

Comment: what  do you mean by *i does not even read the barcode*? Mind showing some code?

Comment: Okey.For example i started with with the project at this link:https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded .And i call this   IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);                                        integrator.initiateScan();

Comment: it scans normal barcode but not white on black.Can you help me more with your solution or library use.Thanks alot

Comment: I never used that library. I quickly looked it up, and I don't think you can use `IntentIntegrator` to scan inverted QR

Answer (score 0):

Update your code with this snippet:

```
import { BarcodeFormat, HTMLCanvasElementLuminanceSource } from '@zxing/library';
  ngOnInit() {
   
    HTMLCanvasElementLuminanceSource.makeBufferFromCanvasImageData = function (canvas) {
      var imageData = canvas.getContext('2d').getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      if(localStorage.inverted.toString()==="true"){
        
        for (var i = 0; i < imageData.data.length; i += 4) {
          var r = imageData.data[i]; // Red color lies between 0 and 255
          var g = imageData.data[i + 1]; // Green color lies between 0 and 255
          var b = imageData.data[i + 2]; // Blue color lies between 0 and 255
          var a = imageData.data[i + 3]; // Transparency lies between 0 and 255
  
          var invertedRed = 255 - r;
          var invertedGreen = 255 - g;
          var invertedBlue = 255 - b;
  
          imageData.data[i] = invertedRed;
          imageData.data[i + 1] = invertedGreen;
          imageData.data[i + 2] = invertedBlue;
        }
      }
     
      return HTMLCanvasElementLuminanceSource.toGrayscaleBuffer(imageData.data, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  };
}
```